# replicate standard_ds3_v2 databricks cluster in docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

replicating standard_ds3_v2 databricks cluster in docker (14gb 4 cores)
would I just change the spark worker 1 and 2 in dockerfile from 512MB each to 7GB and from 1 core to 2. would this result in the exact same config as the standard_ds3_v2 data bricks cluster?

below is the docker cofig

```
version: "3.6"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyterlab
    container_name: jupyterlab
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-master:
    image: spark-master
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
  spark-worker-1:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
  spark-worker-2:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512m
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You'll never get it replicated 1:1 just because Databricks uses custom version of the Spark, with some features that aren't available in OSS

Comment: @Alex Ott Want to be able to run pyspark applications in azure pipelines. At the moment using databricks but want to remove databricks.  Manually create cluster and run ETL using spark. the idea is to use docker to create the cluster and have a python script that uses pyspark.

Comment: doesn't have to be perfect 1:1 just the approx the  amount of compute would be good enough